# how to avoid averageifs #DIV/0! using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have the below code:

```
Sheet1.Range("AB3").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.AverageIfs( _
                                .Range("AB5:AB" & CStr(i)), _
                                .Range("AB5:AB" & CStr(i)), _
                                ">=0", .Range("AB5:AB" & CStr(i)), "<>N/A")
```

To get the average of a range and exclude `-ve` values and `N/A` values, but there is a moment when all range is `N/A`, so I'm getting the following error:

```
unable to get the average property of the worksheetfunction class
```

To avoid that I tried this:

```
Sheet1.Range("AB3").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.IfError( _
                                Application.WorksheetFunction.AverageIfs( _
                                .Range("AB5:AB" & CStr(i)), _
                                .Range("AB5:AB" & CStr(i)), ">=0", _
                                .Range("AB5:AB" & CStr(i)), "<>N/A"), "N/A")
```

But with no luck. Any help will be appreciated.

EDIT:

In excel it works ok, but not in vba (in the code behind)

Just doing a little test in excel it works fine:

```
=IFERROR(AVERAGEIFS(AF5:AF10,AF5:AF10,"<>n/a"),"N/A")
```

in the above formula if data in range "AF5:AF10" is all "n/a", the formula returns "N/A" which is correct.

Comment: could you be clearer `In Excel it works`? which formula do you expect? what do you intend to do?

Comment: Please refer to edited above, thx

Comment: Not answering the question(!) but note that AVERAGEIFS will ignore text values like N/A so you don't need to explicitly exclude - this formula should be sufficient `=AVERAGEIF(AF5:AF10,">=0")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd just apply the formula to the cell in code.  Here's two ways, one that puts the formula in the activecell and then "pastes" over it as a value, one that evaluates the formula and then puts that value in the activecell:

```
Sub Test1()
Dim i As Long

i = 10
Sheet1.Range("AB3").Formula = "=IFERROR(AVERAGEIFS(AF5:AF" & CStr(i) & ",AF5:AF" & CStr(i) & ",""<>n/a""),""N/A"")"
Sheet1.Range("B3").Value = Sheet1.Range("AB3").Value
End Sub

Sub Test2()
Dim strFormula As String
Dim i As Long

i = 10
strFormula = "=IFERROR(AVERAGEIFS(AF5:AF" & CStr(i) & ",AF5:AF" & CStr(i) & ",""<>n/a""),""N/A"")"
Sheet1.Range("AB3").Value = Application.Evaluate(strFormula)
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm still having the `unable to get the average property of the worksheetfunction class` I guess is something related with the formula itself, not the way the result is assigned to the cell.

Comment: There is no "worksheetfunction" in either of the pieces of code I suggested.  Did you use the code exactly as above?  I'd do a Ctrl-F for "worksheetfunction" and make sure you got rid of it.

Comment: If I don't put the Application.WorksheetFunction before the specific function then I have: `Compile error: Sub or Function not defined`

Comment: There is no "specific function" in the examples I provided.  Could you try just running the code?  They are stand-alone examples designed to show you how to approach the problem in your code.

Comment: Thx for helping me Doug, but what can I say, if I removed the Application.WorksheetFunction, then I get the above error. I don't know, could be my version of excel [2007]

Comment: Did you try running either sub above stand-alone?

Comment: Yeap, stand-alone works, so I have to start from there, thx :)

Comment: Great!  BTW, my business name is yoursumbuddy, so I'm glad we to to work together.

Answer (score 0):

I found another solution to my question:

to avoid the:

```
unable to get the average property of the worksheetfunction class
```

just remove `WorksheetFunction` from the formula.

That's it.

Comment: According to this article by Chip Pearson, removing WorksheetFunction requires you to test for errors more explicitly: http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/CallingWorksheetFunctionsInVBA.aspx .  Look for the "Error Handling With Worksheet Functions" section.  The gist is: "If you do include the WorksheetFunction property, errors will manifest themselves as runtime error ... If you do not include the WorksheetFunction property, you must declare the result variable as a Variant type and test that variable with the IsError function."